# изменить тип поля VARCHAR на DATE

Tags: mysql, дата

Два года назад была создана база, сейчас хочется ее немного привести в порядок.

Было неправильно выбрано (по неопытности) хранение даты в обычном varchar, запись идет туда в виде числа UNIXTIME.

Хочу изменить тип поля VARCHAR на DATE.

Можно ли сделать это быстро через сам mysql запрос в phpMyAdmin?
Или придётся писать функцию, выбирать каждое поле, преобразовывать unix в YYYY-MM-DD, и записывать его обратно? А после этого уже менять тип?

Число строк около 3000.

Comment: В каком формате у Вас хранится дата? В unix-time?

Comment: Unix (1519553435)

Comment: Т.е. только число?

Comment: да, получается просто число. точнее строка так как храниться в поле типа VARCHAR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый быстрый способ такой

1. Создаете новый столбец типа TIMESTAMP/DATETIME
2. Выполняете запрос

   ```
   UPDATE mytable SET new_col = FROM_UNIXTIME(old_col);
   ```
3. Удаляете старый столбец
4. Переименовываете новый столбец в старое имя

Comment: Супер, спасибо!

Comment: Хотел поставить +, но ругается что у меня репутация меньше 15. Так что, просто спасибо.